# C# A loop using while. Variable displayed only once

Tags: c#, loops, console

I have a small problem. My code is this one :

```
int c = 0;
int i = 0;
int a = 28;
while (i < a) {
    i++;
    if (i % a == 0) {
        c += i;
        Console.WriteLine(i.ToString());
    }
}
```

Why does the string i is displayed only once, after the end of the while ? It should be displayed a times.

Your help will be appreciated !

Comment: Step through this with the debugger.

Comment: You are playing with the [perfect number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_number) 28. You are trying to sum up all numbers `i` that divide 28, but because you put the operands in the wrong order, you sum all numbers `i` that 28 divides.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `if` condition is opposite it should be:

```
 if (a % i == 0)
```

Currently you are trying to do remainder division with `i % a` and it will only meet the condition when `i` reaches `28`, so you get the output once.

Answer (score 0):

`%` is for modulus division, which basically divides by the number and gives you back the remainder. When you're loop reaches 28 it divides it by 28 and the resulting remainder is 0. This only happens once "when your loop reaches 28".

Answer (score 0):

It would help if you told us what was printed out. I guess it is 28 because

```
i % a
```

returns the reminder of

```
i / a
```

(i divided by a) and it is only 0 when i is equal to a, i.e., 28.